# Converting a column of Array of Array to Array type in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like below:

```
+---+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|uid|label|features                                                                                          |weight|
+---+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|1  |1.0  |[WrappedArray([animal_indexed,2.0,animal_indexed]), WrappedArray([talk_indexed,3.0,talk_indexed])]|1     |
|2  |0.0  |[WrappedArray([animal_indexed,1.0,animal_indexed]), WrappedArray([talk_indexed,2.0,talk_indexed])]|1     |
|3  |1.0  |[WrappedArray([animal_indexed,0.0,animal_indexed]), WrappedArray([talk_indexed,1.0,talk_indexed])]|1     |
|4  |2.0  |[WrappedArray([animal_indexed,0.0,animal_indexed]), WrappedArray([talk_indexed,0.0,talk_indexed])]|1     |
+---+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

and the schema is

```
root
 |-- uid: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- label: double (nullable = false)
 |-- features: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- term: string (nullable = true)
 |-- weight: integer (nullable = false)
```

But I want to convert the features from Array[Array] to just Array
i.e. flatMap a column array into the same column to get a schema like

```
  root
     |-- uid: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- label: double (nullable = false)
     |-- features: array (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = false)
     |    |    |    |-- term: string (nullable = true)
     |-- weight: integer (nullable = false)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with explode function

Comment: I dont want to get multiple rows from same row. Rather remove the extra nesting in the dataFrame 

i.e from Array[Array[]] to Array[] using something similar to flatten operation on array.

Comment: Could you try the flatten function on your array? All scala collections have this function.

Comment: @PJFanning can you give an example for a sample dataframe column and converting it from Array[Array] to Array type?

Comment: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5458351705459939/584889601849365/5521341683971298/latest.html

Answer (score 1):

You should read your data as a Dataset with schema:

```
case class Something(name: String, value: Double, term: String)
case class MyClass(uid: Int, label: Double, array: Seq[Seq[Something]], weight: Int)
```

then use UDF like this:

```
val flatUDF = udf((list: Seq[Seq[Something]]) => list.flatten)

val flattedDF = myDataFrame.withColumn("flatten", flatUDF($"features"))
```

example for reading dataset:

```
val myDataFrame = spark.read.json(path).as[MyClass]
```

Hope this helps.